How to determine if the user’s screen is locked in windows (using Go)?
How can I determine if the user’s screen is locked in Windows? I'm writing in Go, but I think this is more about the WinAPI.
Currently, I’m using the following function:
const DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100

func main() {
    for range time.Tick(time.Second) {
        fmt.Println("LockDesktop = ", LockDesktop())
    }
}

func LockDesktop() bool {
    h := winApi.OpenDesktop("Default", 0, false, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
    defer winApi.CloseDesktop(h)

    if h != 0 {
        return !winApi.SwitchDesktop(h)
    }

    return false
}


This function works somewhat. For example, when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del, I see LockDesktop = true in the console. However, if I lock the screen using Win+L, the console shows LockDesktop = false. Only when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del again (to bring up the password input screen), does LockDesktop = true start appearing in the console again (also during UAC prompts, LockDesktop = true is displayed).
How can I ensure that LockDesktop = true is returned even when the screen is locked (using Win+L)?

UPD
decided in a simple way, I get the title of the window.
func main() {
    for range time.Tick(time.Second) {
        fmt.Println("LockDesktop = ", LockDesktop() || IsDefaultLockScreen())
    }
}


func IsDefaultLockScreen() bool {
    hwnd := GetForegroundWindow()
    windowText := GetWindowText(hwnd)

    return windowText == "Windows Default Lock Screen" 
}


You can try this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw
You should check for the value WTSDisconnected.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-wts_connectstate_class
